# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'service'

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, appsettings

I have an asp.net core MVC application and I get an error after scaffolding.

My connection string is as follows `appsettings.json`

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyNewDatabase": "data source=.; initial catalog=MyNewDb; integrated security=true"
  }
```

And the error I encountered:

```
> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'service'.
```

I take it to the comment line in `Startup.cs` because if I don't take it to the comment line, it gives an error here

```
> app.UseMvc(routes => {
>                 routes.MapRoute(
>                 name: "default",
>                 template: "{Controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
>             });
```

Comment: Need to see some code like in your startup file.  What version of .net core are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.1.0 version of .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following code in `Startup.cs`

```
> app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>             {
>                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
>                     name: "default",
>                     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
>             });
```

And I added the following code in `AppDbContext.cs`

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"data source=.; initial catalog=MyNewDb; integrated security=true");
```